# ANTLR - Handle whitespace in identifier

Tags: antlr4

I am trying to build simple search expression, and couldn't get right answer to below grammar.

```
Here are my sample search text 
LOB WHERE 
Line of Business WHERE 
Line of     Business WHERE
```

As you can see in above search, first few words reflect search keyword followed by where condition, i want to capture search keyword that can include whitespace. Sharing following sample grammar but doesn't seems to parse properly

```
sqlsyntax : identifierws 'WHERE';  
identifierws :  (WSID)+;
WSID: [a-zA-Z0-9 ] ;      // match identifiers with space
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines
```

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

This is what is happening when I try to parse 
Line of      Business WHERE

I get following error
line 1:0 no viable alternative at input 'Line'
I get back LineofBusiness text but whitespace got trimmed, i want exact text Line of     Business, that is where I am struggling a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The `identeriferws` rule is consuming all text. Better to prioritize identification of keywords in the lexer:

```
sqlsyntax : identifierws WHERE identifierws EQ STRING EOF ;  
identifierws :  (WSID)+;
WHERE: 'WHERE';
EQ : '=' ;
STRING : '\'' .? '\'' ;
WSID: [a-zA-Z0-9 ] ;      
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Comment: Thank you GRosenberg for your reply, but issue is bit different, I re-phrased my question to give better clarity. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For such a simple case I wouldn't use a parser. That's just overkill. All you need to do is to get the current position in the input then search for WHERE (a simple boyer-moore search). Then take the text between start position and WHERE position as your input. Jump over WHERE and set the start position to where you are then. After that do the same search again etc.

Comment: Mike - Thanks for your response, what i have shared is a very small snippet of very big grammar i am trying to build, to simplify the problem, i just gave a small example of where I am having issues. But ofcourse, if it was so simple as illustrated in example, i will never use ANTLR ;-) i am building my own domain language and whitespace handling in identifier is where I am kind of stuck.